# Number of Gaussian primes in a convex domain

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

Suppose  $ D $  is a convex domain of the complex plane with isobarycenter  $ z $ and whose area is  $ S $ . Are there  $ O(S/\log^{2}\vert z\vert) $ Gaussian primes in  $ D $?